# Can't install Android ADT to Eclipse Helios (Windows)

Tags: android, eclipse

Can't install Android ADT to Eclipe Helios causing errors:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.java 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse UI 3.7.0.I20110602-0100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.7.0.I20110602-0100)
    Eclipse UI 3.5.2.M20100120-0800 (org.eclipse.ui 3.5.2.M20100120-0800)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.1.M20100826-1330 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.1.M20100826-1330)
    Eclipse UI 3.5.1.M20090902-1000 (org.eclipse.ui 3.5.1.M20090902-1000)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.0.I20100603-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0.I20100603-1100)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
    To: org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.java 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.java.feature.feature.group [1.3.1.20100916-1202]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EPP Java Package 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (org.eclipse.epp.package.java.feature.feature.group 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T)
    To: org.eclipse.ui [3.6.1.M20100826-1330]
```

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really can't do fresh install as my Eclipse is fully loaded with other features that I use in my projects. And migrating features from existing Eclipse install to new install is painful in my experience (not considering if it will work).

So I just unpacked the ADT zip file into the Eclipse install then it worked.

Comment: What is the installation folder? Are you pointing at the 'plugins' folder?

Answer (score 6):

Download [ADT Plugin](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-16.0.1.zip) , unzip and copy all folders (features, plugins, web ...) into your Eclipse installation folder.

Comment: This works like a charm, just to elaborate here. Copy the jar files from 'features' of ADT-18.0.0(here I have the version 18) into the eclipse>feature folder, just copy and paste no need to create any folders. Also from the plugins folder, copy all the jars into eclipse>plugin folder and finally the web folder into the eclipse>web folder or if not present just copy the folder itself into eclipse folder.

Answer (score 3):

if You used window 7 than try Run as Administrator

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I found was to reinstall Eclipse from scratch. This is actually fairly easy, since all you have to do is unzip the package.

So, I took the opportunity to upgrade to Eclipse Indigo at the same time.

Comment: +1 it is good to re-install eclipse but its great to solve problem and gather lots of experience

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I tried copying all the files from  [ADT PLUGIN](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-16.0.1.zip) , re-installed eclipse but none of them seemed to help. Only updating eclipse (Help > Check for Updates) solved the issue.

BNW,  [STACK OVERFLOW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955731/whats-wrong-when-i-try-to-install-adt-on-eclipse)  has the same discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Error messages can be surprisingly useful.  The error message says you have a conflicting dependency.  If it were my box I'd probably uninstall all instances of Eclipse, then install the one you want and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Just unzip the ADT and copy the contents to appropriate folders in eclipse installation. Restart Eclipse. The issue will be solved.

Comment: Thanks, but the question has long been answered

Answer (score 0):

If you have come to this old thread while trying to upgrade your Eclipse Helios SDK to Lollipop, note the dependencies:

ADT 23.0.4 (October 2014)

Your existing Eclipse installation must meet these requirements:

- Eclipse 3.7.2 (Indigo) or greater

  - Note: **Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) is no longer supported** with the latest version of ADT.
- Eclipse JDT plugin (included in most Eclipse IDE packages)
- JDK 6 (JRE alone is not sufficient)
- Not compatible with GNU Compiler for Java (gcj)

I upgraded to Eclipse Luna and these errors did not reappear.