# What's wrong when I try to install ADT on Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

**How to fix this?**

```
> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.  
> Software being installed: Android DDMS 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
> (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group
> 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)   Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.jee
> 1.3.1.20100916-1202)   Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
>     Eclipse UI 3.6.1.M20100826-1330 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.1.M20100826-1330)
>     Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
>     Eclipse UI 3.6.0.I20100603-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0.I20100603-1100)   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: Android DDMS 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group
> 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
>     To: org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.jee 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
>     To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.3.1.20100916-1202]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group
> 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
>     To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L]   Cannot
> satisfy dependency:
```

Comment: Try doing help | update first, install everything recommended, and then try to install ADT.

Comment: Propably should read this better - http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

Comment: And installed the eclipse-java-indigo-SR1-win32 instead.

Comment: Now I got it working and started coding!

Answer (score 3):

You use old version of Eclipse(3.6). This version isn't support ADT 16 plugin. Instal more new version of Eclipse such as Helios or Indigo

Answer (score 0):

I had the same (or at least, similar) problem as you did when installing ADT, and this was what I came up with:

If you installed Eclipse from another source than [the official website](http://www.eclipse.org), you might have the Eclipse update sites disabled. To fix this, open Eclipse and go to `Help -> Install new sotfware` and click "Available software sites". From there, you can enable the update site for your version of Eclipse (for 3.7, for instance, the URL should look like [`http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7`](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7) - the entire list can be found [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites)). When you have enabled it, go back and retry installing the ADT plugin. It should work perfectly now, at least it did for me.

Comment: What about eclipse-jee-indigo-SR1-win32?