# dependency problems installing ADT with Helios

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

nooby I'm afraid.

Windows7 32bit
Java 1.7.0_04
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Helios Release
Build id: 20100617-1415
android-sdk_r18
ADT 18.0.0

Followed instructions on Android site to install the above. Problem occurred during the downloading the ADT plugin stage. Reported a list of dependency problems. I have the error log available if it helps.

In a fit of hopefulness, tried going on to the next phase but Android not listed in the Preferences dialog.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It may duplicate with this question : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602129/cant-install-android-adt-to-eclipse-helios-windows`

Comment: I have this error on my Indigo Java2SE version, but i switch to JavaEE and it installs without any warning and error :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have appended the important parts of the error message. The general answer would be to install the dependencies and try again.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The problem was actually conflicting dependencies rather than missing ones. I wasn't sure about the etiquette of posting great swathes of error log, but I'll paste it after this. My more focused question then becomes;  How do I locate the duplicate files and how do I know which ones to delete?